# Is my proof for $f(0)=1$ for a specific continuous function correct?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

Alright, I think I have found a much simpler proof to a question than the one I was provided with, and wanted to hear how it is inevitably incorrect.

Let $f$ be a continuous function that you can always get the derivative of and that is always positive. Additionally,

$f'(0)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-1}{x}$

prove $f(0)=1$

I proved it as such:

According to the definition of a continuous function:

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=f(c)$

Therefore:

$f'(0)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f(x)-1}{x}=\frac{f(c)-1}{c}\Rightarrow c\cdot f'(0)=f(c)-1$

Let $c=0:$

$f(0)-1=0\Rightarrow f(0)=1 \blacksquare$

Comment: the idea is nice but not correct. When you write $\frac{f(c)-1}{c}$ you assume implicitly that $c\neq 0$, so you can not plug $c=0$ directly.

Comment: You used the fact that the limit of the quotient is the quotient of the limits, which is not $necessarily$ true because  lim denominator $= 0$.

Comment: lim f (x)=f (c) only is true if f (c) exists.  (f (c)-1)/c for c = 0 doesn't exist.  What you did was the equivalent of if h =jx/x then h=j so 0x7=0x8 so 7=0x8/0=8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is not correct. By definition,

$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-1}{x}$$

so,

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-1}{x}=0\to \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(0)-1}{x}=0\quad (1)$$

but

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{c}{x}=c\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$$

**Doesn't exist** if $c\ne 0$ and it is a constant number.

Then if $(1)$ is true you must have $f(0)=1$.

*P.S.: Your solution in not correct because when you write $c\cdot f'(0)=f(c)-1$ you are assuming that $c\ne 0$.*

Comment: Could I say that for $f'(0)$ to exist we must have $\frac{1-1}{0}$, because in any other case we have a division by zero?

Comment: @CluelessButCurious: Not exactly, because we are talking about limit not an exact division.

Comment: but once I move it to $f'(0)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f(x)-1}{x}=\frac{f(0)-1}{0}$ isn't that normal division?

Comment: @CluelessButCurious: no it isn't, because $x\to 0$ means that $x$ is getting close to $0$ but It doesn't reach $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is incorrect, because you can't write
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-1}{x}=\frac{f(c)-1}{c}
$$
Intuitively, $f(0)=1$ because otherwise the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-1}{x}
$$
cannot exist finite.

More rigorously,
$$
f(0)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=
\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+\frac{f(x)-1}{x}x\right)=
1+\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-1}{x}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}x
$$
because the limits in the last term exist finite.